# Why did Old English lose both thorn and eth?

Tags: orthography, old-english

My understanding is that Old English had two letters, thorn and eth, which were used interchangeably to represent the sound *th* as in *thin* or *father*.

Intuitively, one might think that one of these letters would 'win', and replace the other.

Instead, we lost **both** of these letters and use the digraph *th* instead.

Why did this happen?

Answer (score 165, accepted):

> My understanding is that Old English had two letters, thorn and eth, which were used interchangeably to represent the sound *th* as in *thin* or *father*.

Pretty much. In some languages they were distinct, but in English, either letter could be used for voiced or voiceless.

> Intuitively, one might think that one of these letters would 'win', and replace the other.

Indeed: thorn *(þ)* won, and eth *(ð)* died out.

> Instead, we lost **both** of these letters and use the digraph *th* instead.

Eth was lost early, within Old English; thorn survived all the way into Early Modern English, and is found in the first printing of the King James Bible. (Norman) French influences brought about some use of *th*, but *þ* was still widely popular and universally understood.

But German, French, Italian, and other prominent languages of the time didn't use thorn, and thus typefaces imported from Europe didn't include it. So in printed books, thorn generally had to be replaced either with *th*, or with the closest available character, *y*; the latter was readable, but somewhat annoying and unintuitive (since *þ* and *y* are pronounced nothing alike).

So the convention of using *th* took over, and *þ* vanished entirely. The use of *y* survives only in archaicisms like "ye olde shoppe", where it's now pronounced `/j/` instead.

And English-speakers, understanding that revenge was a dish best served cold, went on to impose ASCII on the world and destroy dozens and dozens of other languages' unique letters in the same way. All of which could have been avoided if Johannes Gutenberg had stuck to Unicode from the beginning.

Comment: (Note: the last paragraph is not to be taken seriously. Johannes Gutenberg had very good reasons not to use Unicode from the beginning, such as living several centuries before Unicode was proposed.)

Comment: What is the complex mapping in your profile photo?

Comment: Unicode compliance with the full emoji set would have been cost-prohibitive for most small-time printers.

Comment: More than this, it was the influence of the Normans who brought over the pure Latin alphabet and had a distaste for the "weird" English characters (not that they wrote in English initially). It was the same with some other spelling normalisation rules. In any case, the Normans made up the vast majority of literate society following the Conquest, and their influence was profound, even as the native English made a resurgence (having been heavily influenced by Anglo-Norman and later Parisian French).

Comment: @chrylis now I want to see a lead type set for the emoji.

Comment: so why was th chosen?

Comment: @tox123 My best guess is https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/a/29626/10559

Comment: @Noldorin Also true; feel free to post that as another answer!

Comment: so only Icelandic was sufficiently remote and isolated back then to keep both?The mention of "ye olde ..." answers another question that I (and likely many others) never thought of asking... fir me it was clear that it cannot be anything else than an archaic "your" - again, learned something new today.

Comment: @dlatikay Icelandic had a stronger attachment to its extra letters, and didn't have the Normans coming in and making French (which lacked þ and ð) the prestige language. And indeed! "Ye olde" was originally "þe olde", that is, "the old".

Comment: @ChaseRyanTaylor sin(1/z), with the real and imaginary parts of the input between -1 and 1, and the magnitude of the output capped at 5

Comment: @Draconis Yeah, I thought about it, but I thought it better just as an addendum to your answer. Thanks... and feel free to incorporate it if you like.

Comment: Strange, the printing did not prevent the rise of diacritics in Czech at the time. The German type creators were capable of creating diacritic letters for Czech printers. They should have been able to make one extra letter.

Comment: I want to award you gold for that last paragraph.

Comment: @chrylis yes, but think how much more fun the Bible would have been to read, if Gutenburg had used emojis.

Comment: You want emojis? Read hieroglyphics! I would insert some here but am too ignorant...

Comment: The "y" was also often originally *yet another* now-missing letter, called "yogh" ("ȝ"), which has been replaced by either "y" or "gh", depending on the word (e.g. "plouȝ" → "plough")

Comment: @chrylis I think they could afford to at least support Windows-1252 or ISO 8859-1.

Comment: So when you see something like "Ye Olde Curiosity Shoppe", that first word is meant to be pronounced "The". (And if you want to be particularly early modern about it, the trailing 'e' characters on "olde" and "shoppe" should be voiced as well, so this should be "the old-eh curiosity shop-eh").

Comment: @BobJarvis Indeed—though of course pronouncing "old" and "shop" the modern way isn't *wrong*, per se; word-final E went silent before þ was entirely lost, so there was some overlap in the middle.

Comment: @Draconis - sure - and when I see words like that I pronounce them as "Yee Old Curiosity Shop" - but it's interesting to know that those "silent" E's were sounded out at one time. :-)

Comment: @VladimirF Printing was largely concentrated in Italy, Germany and France (in that order). English and Czech printing combined made up less than 2% of original production. But here's the interesting bit - Europe-wide, most of production was in latin (~72%). The Czech original production was ~90% in Czech (taking #1), compared to ~30% in German, for example. English actually takes second place with ~60%. This probably has to do with religious differences. In the end, adding just one character to English typesets probably wasn't worth the effort; it's more important in Czech typesets.

Comment: @VladimirF Keep in mind that alternatives like using "rz" instead of "ř" didn't save any effort - the typesets would still use a single "rz" letter for the former. Indeed, the early typesets for Czech language included some of these (Tiskař Arnoštových Statut used "r", "ř" and "rz", as well as using "ff" instead of "š", among many other differences to modern types).

Answer (score 15):

The explanation I remember seeing for the rise of the digraph “th” and fall of the letters thorn and eth in English spelling is influence from French spelling habits.

You can see more details if you do a search for "digraph" in the paper "[The evolution of English dental fricatives:
variation and change](https://repozytorium.amu.edu.pl/bitstream/10593/11002/1/Jekiel%20%E2%80%93%202012%20%E2%80%93%20The%20evolution%20of%20English%20dental%20fricatives%20%E2%80%93%20variation%20and%20change.pdf)", by Mateusz Jekiel (2012). Note that the history of the spelling of non-sibilant dental fricatives in English is fairly complicated and includes a lot of variation.

The digraph "th" had actually been used early on in the Old English period (alongside the letter "d" in medial or final positions). Jekiel says

> According to
>   Hogg (1992b: 76-77), the <th> digraph appeared first by the end of the 8th c. in early OE
>   manuscripts, as it was borrowed from the Irish and spread by monks who taught Latin. Furthermore, <th> also appeared in the 9th c. Old Saxon, where the grapheme represented only
>   the voiceless dental fricative.

(p. 52)

The use of the letter thorn lasted substantially past the Old English period, and even into Early Modern English in certain specific contexts: many function words starting with the th sound had abbreviations starting with thorn, which came to be written in a way that looked like the letter y. This is the source of “ye” as a spelling for the word “the”.

Answer (score 12):

Here are my *notes* on the question, a summary of most important linguistic research with relevant quotes; perhaps someone, who is more into linguistic theory, might find them useful.

**Old English**

[Hogg 1992 (2005)](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/cambridge-history-of-the-english-language/phonology-and-morphology/A8D95BCB691F2F39E767D11F8ED93441):

1. “Orthographic usage was reasonably stable during the Old English period”;
   “Anglo-Saxon manuscripts of Latin normally kept to the Latin spelling conventions and alphabet, and in the earliest vernacular manuscripts the spelling system remained close to that of Latin texts, usually of Irish origin.”; thus, he continues,

> “at first, we do **not** find spellings with <æ>, <w>, <þ> or <ð>” (p. 71; emphasis mine - Alex B.), Hoggs calls the use of <þ> or <ð>” **the Anglo-Saxon innovations** (p. 77) because in the very earliest manuscripts, especially from the north, we find the digraph *th* or the simple graph *d* ([Hogg 1992/2011](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/9781444341355.ch2) mentions Bede(M), EpGl and the later LVD (p. 33);

2. <þ> and <ð> “were in principle interchangeable with one another, whatever the generality of their usage or the habits of individual scribes” (p. 76), for instance, he quotes the following spelling variants from Beowulf, syððan (line 6), syðþan (line 132), syþðan (line 283), and syþþan (line 604).
3. <þ> and <ð> “must have been used by the last quarter of the seventh century”;
4. Differences in usage: at first, <ð> was the most frequent choice (up to about the time of Alfred); later, <þ> was more and more used, mainly restricted to initial position (with some occasional instances in medial position and rare in final position).

**ð eth (or edh):** “the native English term appears to have been ðæt” ([Robinson 1973:](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2854443) 451); Hogg 1992: 75 adds that since the nineteenth century it has been known under its current name (Robinson 1973: 451 mentions its current name was borrowed from Modern Icelandic but Hoggs claims that “this is uncertain”).

**digraph th:** “appears to have been borrowed from Irish” (Hogg, p. 77);

**Middle English**

Lass 1992 writes that “<ð> began to yield to <þ> in the thirteenth century, though it remains sporadically through the fourteenth” (p. 36) - against an incorrect assertion in one of the other answers posted here. He adds that in Early Middle English <þ> was the most common graphical representation for /θ, ð/, although the digraph th ‘reappears’ in the twelfth century and gradually ousts <þ>.

[Upward and Davidson 2011:](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/book/10.1002/9781444342994)
“Through the ME period this TH was increasingly adopted in place of the OE symbols Þ and Ð to represent the native Eng voiced and voiceless sounds /ð, θ/” (p. 160). They list it under **“Spelling changes introduced by Anglo-Norman scribes”** (p. 176, emphasis mine - Alex B.).

> Upward and Davidson 2011 mention that this *gradual* change was completed by about the end of the 15th century” (p. 176).

In passim, they make an accurate observation, almost a truism I'd say, about TH "being **more economical** and **not susceptible to misreading** as T+H" (p. 199, emphasis mine - Alex B.).

They add that “the digraph TH is not normally found in Eng words of pure Lat (as opposed to Graeco-Lat) or Fr derivation” (with some exceptions: faith, author, authority, anthem, and thyme) – see p. 199-200 for more details.

**Why?**

As I wrote [elsewhere](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/a/13280/445), drawing on Blake 2012, after the Norman Conquest, English monasteries started receiving a lot of monks trained in France who started copying OE texts applying spelling practices found in the languages they were familiar with (Old French and Latin?). Those practices were further spread by the other monks whose native language was English but who got trained primarily in Old French and a bit of Latin - Cecily Clark (Clark 1992) calls them the Gallicizing scribes.

**Printing**

In Scragg 1974 we can read that William Caxton, the first English printer, usually used the digraph th and only occasionally used a modified form of <þ>, the latter survived in private documents and in some printed books until the seventeenth century, esp. in the contracted forms of the definite article y<sup>e</sup> and demonstrative y<sup>t</sup> (p. 2).

But by that time th had already practically ousted <þ>, which had happened *before* printing.

For example, here's a passage from Raoul Lefèvre (translated by William Caxton), [The Recuyell of the Historyes of Troye (1473)](https://www.bl.uk/learning/timeline/item126577.html).

cf. the following quote from [Jensen 2012](http://www.helsinki.fi/varieng/series/volumes/10/jensen/):

> "The gradual loss of <þ> in favour of <th> in the English spelling system has traditionally been explained by the introduction of print. However, **Stenroos (2006: 10) argues that the replacement of <þ> was a gradual process that had begun long before the advent of printing.** She bases her argument on the following three points. Firstly, the use of <th> appears in the southern part of England already as early as ca 1300 and grows steadily more common through the fourteenth and fifteenth centuries. Secondly, Scragg (1974: 67) suggests that printing and scribal traditions may have been relatively isolated from each other until well into the sixteenth century. Thirdly, it is not completely obvious that the carrying over of thorn into printing would have posed an insurmountable problem: some types used in England did include thorn, and the letter ‘y’ was always available."

**Re: father**

In Old English, this word was always spelled with the simple graph d. The PDE spelling with the digraph th is a Middle English innovation.